# How to disable Windows' Compatibility Assistant?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility

This evening I booted my computer to see a message:

> Speccy was removed from your PC because it doesn't work with your version of Windows.

Sure enough the program (Speccy) was gone from the start menu and from program files.

How can I disable the Windows compatibility assistant so that this doesn't happen again?

Comment: I found `Speccy.exe` hidden in `c:\Windows.old` it seems Windows didn't delete it completely. It runs fine so I still don't know what the fuss was about.

Comment: That `windows.old` folder is 17 GB big, 10% of my hard drive. I wish Windows asked before spewing copies of itself.

Comment: "I wish Windows asked before spewing copies of itself."  It did, a long time go, and you told it to update itself automatically.  Start doing your Windows Updates manually and it'll ask every time. :)  PS: running a  Disk Cleanup will safely remove that windows.old folder for you.

Comment: It did ask; or at least said it would; my guess you installed Version 1511.  Grab what you want out of perform you perform the clean operation!